# Interest rate working as different percentage as needed

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

Not sure of why this is happening but interest rate should be 17.9% but working as 19.something%. I've tried numerous ways to fix it but can't get it to work exactly right. For Example, up to that point, I had €200 as my total. 17.9% should make interest €35.80. But what's coming up is €38.89  Any ideas?

```
Public Class frmFinancePackage

'Interest rate = 17.9%
Const interestRate As Decimal = 0.179
'this method will calculate the compound interest for the 
'finance package and calculate payments

Private Sub frmFinancePackage_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

txtGrossTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(runningCost)

End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, _
         e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
'Declaring local variables
Dim NumYears As Integer
Dim GrossTotal As Decimal
Dim PaymentDue As Integer
Dim NetTotal As Decimal

'Assigning a value to the numYears variable based on which radio button is checked 
'If no radio button is checked a value of 0 is passed

If rdoOneYear.Checked Then
    NumYears = 1
ElseIf rdoTwoYears.Checked Then
    NumYears = 2
ElseIf rdoThreeYears.Checked Then
    NumYears = 3
End If

GrossTotal = runningCost


'Assign a value to NetTotal by calling a function findNetTotal
'pass the variables NumYears and GrossTotal
NetTotal = findNetTotal(NumYears, GrossTotal)

'Assign a value to paymentDue based on what payment frequency radio button is checked
'pass a vaule of 0 if no radio button is checked
If rdoWeekly.Checked Then
    PaymentDue = 52 * NumYears
ElseIf rdoMonthly.Checked Then
    PaymentDue = 12 * NumYears
ElseIf rdoQuarterly.Checked Then
    PaymentDue = 4 * NumYears
End If


'Displaying the results

txtInterest.Text = FormatCurrency(NetTotal - GrossTotal)
txtNetTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(NetTotal)
txtPayment.Text = FormatCurrency(NetTotal / PaymentDue)

btnContinue.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

'This is the function for finding the NetTotal

```
Private Function findNetTotal(ByVal years As Integer, ByVal total As Decimal) As Decimal

'Declare variables for the function
Dim interest As Decimal
Dim months As Integer = years * 12

'Use a loop to find the net total based on compound interest for the number of years
'compound interst is calculated per month
'return the net total

For i As Integer = 1 To months
    interest = total * (interestRate / 12)
    total += interest
Next
Return total
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Try using 
`Double` for more precision instead of `Integer`

Comment: why the duplicate??? its only been minutes [Interest rate working as different percentage as needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478477/interest-rate-working-as-different-percentage-as-needed)

Comment: If you want to add details to the question, please edit your original question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: OP is only using integers for counting whole things like years, months, etc.  No need to switch that to Double.  Also using Decimal for money which is good.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be right but your test might not be.  When I place the below formula* into Excel it gives me the same value coming out of your findNetTotal function.

=200*(1+(0.179/12))^12
gives 238.8882

When I paste your code (well the constant and findNewTotal) into a local project calling findNewTotal with 1 for years and 200 for total gives 238.88815.... as output, which matches Excel.

So, why do you think 17.9% should come up with 35.80 instead of 38.89?

*Formula comes from MS site on compound interest: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141695